# how to append zmmtg-root inside meetingSDKElement DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, zoom-sdk

I am implementing zoom meeting inside my website. I am using zoom meeting SDK. Everything works well but DOM is appending just above the closing `</html>` tag. HOwever, In my view, I have defined DOM as per zoom instruction.

I am using Codeigniter, jQuery. Below is my code

```
//This is view

<div id="meetingSDKElement"></div>

//This is footer
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.18.2/lib/vendor/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.18.2/lib/vendor/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.18.2/lib/vendor/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.18.2/lib/vendor/redux-thunk.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/2.18.2/lib/vendor/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://source.zoom.us/zoom-meeting-2.18.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/client-view.js'); ?>?v=<?php echo VERSION; ?>"></script>

//This is Javascript
$(document).ready(function(){
   getSignature();
});
function getSignature() {
  fetch(authEndpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
      role: role,
      password:passWord
    })
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    startMeeting(data.signature)
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}

function startMeeting(signature) {
$(".meeting-loader").css("visibility", "hidden");
  document.getElementById('zmmtg-root').style.display = 'block'

  ZoomMtg.init({
    leaveUrl: leaveUrl,
    success: (success) => {
      console.log(success)
      ZoomMtg.join({
        signature: signature,
        sdkKey: sdkKey,
        meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
        passWord: passWord,
        userName: userName,
        userEmail: userEmail,
        tk: registrantToken,
        zak: zakToken,
        success: (success) => {
          console.log(success)
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        },
      })
    },
    error: (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
}
```

I want `zmmtg-root` to be appended inside `meetingSDKElement`.

#### After choosing iFrame Solution mypage is not loading full video, instead a small window of video canvas and there is this big blue banner appeared

[image]

I would like the meeting UI to fit inside the iFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Zoom Developer Advocate here. Since the [Zoom Meeting SDK web Client View](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/web/client-view/) is designed to take up the whole page, it does not support being appended to a given HTML element.

However, there are two approaches to append the Meeting SDK inside a given HTML element:

1. [Embed the Meeting SDK web Client View in an iFrame](https://devsupport.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/13662906729485), keeping your existing code, but hosting and setting it as the iframe src:

   ```html
   <div id="meetingSDKElement">
      <iframe src="https://example.com/meetingsdk" allow="camera; microphone"></iframe>
   </div>
   ```
2. Use the [Meeting SDK web Component View](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/web/component-view/), which is designed to be appended in a given HTML element:

   ```html
   <div id="meetingSDKElement">
     <!-- Meeting SDK renders here when a user starts or joins a Zoom meeting -->
   </div>
   ```

   ```js
   const client = ZoomMtgEmbedded.createClient()

   let meetingSDKElement = document.getElementById('meetingSDKElement')

   client.init({ zoomAppRoot: meetingSDKElement, language: 'en-US' })

   client.join({
      sdkKey: sdkKey,
      signature: signature,
      meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
      password: password,
      userName: userName,
      zak: zakToken
   })
   ```

For questions specific to the Zoom Developer Platform, feel free to ask on the [Zoom devforum](https://devforum.zoom.us/).

Comment: I choose iframe solution but I am getting a big blue banner after clicking on the join button. Have added the screenshot in my initial question, plz check

Comment: Hey @RahulGupta, that screen is the Zoom meeting waiting room. The host of the meeting would have to [admit the user](https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0063329), or you can adjust use meeting settings to use a [passcode](https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0063160) instead of the waiting room.